# No suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<int[]>)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

*Not a duplicate of  '[No suitable constructor found for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662064/no-suitable-constructor-found-for)' nor of '[No Suitable Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599719/no-suitable-constructor)'.*

My aim is to convert an array to an arrayList. I have had a look at [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array)

So I tried:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

where `arr` is an integer array.

On compiling, I got:

> `error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<int[]>)`

So I looked at the docs and found a constructor:

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Since `ArrayList<Integer>remaining = new ArrayList<Integer>(new Stack<Integer>());` compiled without errors, I inferred that passing a List<> (and perhaps any other subinterface of `Collection`) would result in an error, while any class that implemented `Collection` would compile.

The OP of [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array) had asked:

> I have an array that is initialized like:
>
> ```
> Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};
> ```
>
> I would like to convert this array into an object of the ArrayList
>   class.
>
> ```
> ArrayList<Element> arraylist = ???;
> ```

which is exactly what I want to do.

Why did the accepted answer:

> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array))

work for that OP but not for me? Am I overlooking something very small?

EDIT: I had forgotten the keyword 'new'. Added it now. Same error

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry. I had used 'new' earlier and still got the error. Updated the question

Comment: And indeed this *is* a duplicate

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Its the former

Comment: as of jdk8 you could do `List<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(toList());`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! Just saw your comment now for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an `int[]` to `Arrays.asList()`, which means it returns a `List<int[]>`, which is not acceptable for the constructor of an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

If you were creating an `ArrayList<int[]>`, the following would work:

```
ArrayList<int[]> al = new ArrayList<int[]>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

However, I don't think that's what you wanted. You should probably start with an `Integer[]` instead of an `int[]`. Then `Arrays.asList()` would produce a `List<Integer>`, which can be passed to `ArrayList<Integer>` constructor.

Comment: IMHO `ArrayList<int[]> al` is not something worth recommending... talking about programming to interfaces.